# AS3: Managing two TextInputs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am pretty new to AS3 and I'd like to learn from the more experienced ones how to do it right. The problem I have is: having two text inputs, having the ability to change the focus from one to another and the most important one, make the input lose focus on click outside.

The problems I faced here are:

1. When I click outside text inputs, it does not loses focus
2. If I focus in a text input, minimize browser and come back, it auto refocuses the last element.

How do you see this process implemented and what could I do to solve the problems I face?

Answer (score 0):

To drop focus on your textfields, set a mouse event on the stage:

```
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onDropFocus );

function onDropFocus( evt:MouseEvent ):void
{
    Stage.focus = null;
}
```

To reset the proper textfield focus, store a reference to it when you focus in on your textfield, then try listening for **Event.DEACTIVATE** on your stage, which is triggered when the flash movie loses focus.  Then you can refocus to the intended textfield before leaving the page, (like when minimizing).

Comment: clicking on text input does not also trigger a click event on the stage?